# Is it possible to hide specific Product Variations on WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working on a WordPress eCommerce website, where the chosen shopping platform is WooCommerce.

I would like the ability to hide 'Out of Stock' product variations but cannot seem to find a solution, anywhere on the Internet.

For example, say I have a Shoe Shop whereby the website sells Shoes.  Product Drop Down Menu is as follows:

- Shoe Size

  - 9
  - 10
  - 11
- Shoe Colour

  - Red
  - Blue
  - Yellow
- Shoe Style

  - Trainers
  - Casual
  - Velcro

Say the website does not have Blue Size 9 Trainers.  If a shopper selects any 1 of those options from the drop down menu, the other options will be removed/greyed out.

I understand that there is a 'Hide Out of Stock' option, within the WooCommerce Settings but this only affects the Main Product rather than the Product Variations.

I have tried manually deleting the Product Variation, within the Product Page's backend but the variation still exists; a message simply appears saying 'This product is unavailable.  Please select another combination.'

Any guidance on this matter, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
function custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold( $qty, $product ) {
    return 10;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 'custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold', 10, 2 );
```

paste this code into your functions.php file

Comment: why returning 10 ?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Raj Kumar Bhardwaj Unfortunately, this did not work.  Do I need to add anything to the function?  I have noticed that some people state that WooCommerce allows for products to be Greyed out if there is only one variation.  The problem lies if there is more than 1 variation as then you would need to work on Combinations.

Comment: ok lets works on it let me test my end but this is working for me, let's see what can I do for you, so I have questions that is you want to hide variants of the products which is not available currently right?

Comment: Hi Raj, Yes.  I have 4 Product Attributes on a Product Variation.  When a specific Product Variation in the first attribute is selected, I want 'non available' Variations within the other attributes to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply paste the following into functions.php

```
function custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold( $qty, $product ) {
    return 10;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold','custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold', 10, 2 );
```

Then change the 'return 10;' to however many variations you have.

Please note this may slow down page loading time depending on your hosting

Answer (score 0):

First, leave the box to ‘Hide out of stock items from the catalog’ unchecked. Then paste this into the appropriate plugin or theme file:

```
function hide_out_of_products( $is_visible, $id ) {
$product = new wC_Product( $id );

    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock()) {
        $is_visible = false;
    }

    return $is_visible;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'hide_out_of_products', 10, 2 );
```